# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I'm trying do examples from "Spring in action 3". But have this problem and don't understand why.
I have next classes:
My entity:

```
package core;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class SplitterImpl{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="fullname")
    private String fullname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="updatebyemail")
    private String updatebyemail;

    //****************
    //public Setters/getters
    //****************
}
```

My DAO:

```
package core;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class HibernateSplitterDao implements SplitterDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addSplitter(SplitterImpl splitter) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(splitter);       
    }   
}
```

My main class:

```
package core;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static String getBean(){
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("core\\spring.xml");

        return ctx.getBean(HibernateSplitterDao.class).toString();
    }
}
```

in xml spring configuration I'm wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="core"></context:component-scan>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" 
    jndi-name="jdbc/splitter"/> 


    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>


    <bean id="Splitter"
            class="core.SplitterImpl">
        <property name="name" value="TGSH"/>
        <property name="password" value="ua"/>
        <property name="fullname" value="Taras Shevchenko"/>
        <property name="email" value="tgsh@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="updatebyemail" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="core"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>         

    <bean id="dao"  class="core.HibernateSplitterDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I'm trying get some another bean it's all okay. But when I'm trying get HibernateSplitterDao bean, I'm have problem like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [core.HibernateSplitterDao] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:985)
at core.Main.getBean(Main.java:10)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring xml, refer Impl class instead of the Interface.

```
 <bean id="dao"  class="core.HibernateSplitterDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

clean project and run again.

Comment: thx, try delete SplitterDao (inteface) from project. It's work now. But now I have another problem) When try invoc method 'addSpliter' get it:org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: You can add transaction propagation as MANDATORY. Just put @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY) to the DAO method

Comment: Great thanks for help to all. All problems are solved. Last problem solve by add @Transaction to addSplitter method and some xml code:<bean id="transactionManager"  
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">  
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>  
  </bean>
  <tx:annotation-driven/>

Comment: Using <context:component-scan> shouldn't require any bean definition in the xml btw

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a bean of type `SplitterDAO` but you haven't defined any of that class. All I see in the splitter is `core.SplitterImpl`. Try creating a bean that is of type `core.SplitterImpl`.

Comment: SplitterDAO is interface with one method, it's implemented in HibernateSplitterDao.

Comment: Missed that, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

`<context:annotation-config>` is used to enable annotations on beans already registered.(e.g. `@Autowired`)

`<context:component-scan>` takes it a step further and scans to register beans within the context. (e.g. `@Repository`)

Looks like SplitterDao isn't registered (not in xml or not using component-scan)

Comment: I'm add <context:component-scan base-package="core"></context:component-scan> but problem is still exist

Comment: Even if I'm register manually `HibernateSplitterDAO` and try get it by name, i'm get it. But when try cast object to `HibernateSplitterDAO` have it:

    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16 cannot be cast to core.HibernateSplitterDao
     at core.Main.getBean(Main.java:10)
    ....

Comment: can you show your entire xml spring configuration and some of the code you're referring to?

Comment: Add full xml in question.